# What is the coefficient of $ x^{i}$ in the product $ \ \large \prod_{i \geq 1} \frac{1}{1-x^i}\prod_{i \geq 1} \frac{1}{1+x^{2i-1}}$?

Tags: generating-functions, integer-partitions

What is the coefficient of $ x^{i}$ in the product $ \ \large \prod_{i \geq 1} \frac{1}{1-x^i}\prod_{i \geq 1} \frac{1}{1+x^{2i-1}}$?

**Answer:**

$\ \large \prod_{i \geq 1} \frac{1}{1-x^i}\prod_{i \geq 1} \frac{1}{1+x^{2i-1}}$

=$\left\{(1-x)^{-1}(1-x^2)^{-1}(1-x^3)^{-1} \cdots \right\} \left\{(1+x)^{-1}(1+x^3)^{-1} (1+x^5)^{-1} \cdots \right\} $

=$ (1-x)^{-1}(1+x)^{-1}(1-x^2)^{-1}(1-x^3)^{-1}(1+x^3)^{-1} \cdots $

But I am at lost right here.

Help me to find the coefficient of $x^i$, the general coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

The two infinite products multiplied together is the generating function of
[OEIS sequence A015128](http://oeis.org/A015128) which has many kinds of information
about the sequence. For example,

> According to Ramanujan (1913) a(n) is close to $\, (\cosh(x)-\sinh(x)/x)/(4n)$ where $\,x:=\pi\sqrt{n}.\,$

This is only anapproximation whose **relative** error goes to zero. If you want exact values, there are recursions such as $a(n) = -2\sum_{m=1}^{\sqrt{n}} (-1)^m a(n-m^2).$

Comment: Would you answer more explicitly my question ?